# CMAKE does not create INSTALL project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake

I am trying to compile a Library using CMAKE-gui 3.0.2 and Visual Studio express 2013.
Everything seems to be fine during the configuration/generation process in cmake-gui, as I am able to set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable to the path in which I want to have my library installed. And I got no errors during configuration and generation.

I then open the generated `.sln` file in which I can build the `ALL_BUILD` target, which runs smoothly with no errors and no targets skipped.

However, the `INSTALL` target is simply not present in the Solution Explorer, therefore I really do not have any idea on how to install the library.
Upon further inspection, I noticed that cmake did create a file called `cmake_install.cmake`, but I don't know what should I do with it.

Comment: Do you have any `install()` commands in your CMakeList?

Comment: Not in the CMakeList.txt file. In the gui, I can see the variables name and I have just CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH (boolean set to off)

Comment: OK, I meant anywhere in the project where CMake can see it, starting parsing from the toplevel CMakeList.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake will only generate the `INSTALL` target when there is actually anything to install. It would seem you have no `install()` commands in your project.

Presence of the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` does not imply anything - the variable is always present, and is used to control the installation destination when there is anything to install.

Likewise, the file `cmake_install.cmake` is always created; but if you inspect it, you'll find it's basically a no-op in your case (probably just some messages, setting CMake variables and possibly creating a manifest which is not used for anything).

Comment: So why did cmake asked me for an INSTALL_PREFIX and it even created a cmake_install.cmake file? By the way, if you want to take a look by yourself, I am trying to build the library in this folder: [link](https://github.com/royshil/SfM-Toy-Library/tree/master/3rdparty/SSBA-3.0)

Comment: @alef0 I've expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. Just one last question: is it reasonable to assume that this library is just an Header only library, thus I can just use it by copying the header files in my project?

Comment: @alef0 No, it's not header-only. If you look into its `CMakeLists.txt` file, you'll notice there are several `.cpp` files among its sources.